# How do you break the one tile high speed booster block in Ferenia?

Tags: metroid-dread

Near the top of Ferenia, slightly south-west of the teleporter to Hanubia, there is an icy room with a one tile high speed booster block at the bottom of a wall. Boosting into the block doesn't break it, presumably because the section is too small.

How do you break through this one tile high speed booster block in Ferenia?

[image: Speed booster block]

[image: Map location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slide into the block will break it as long as you've already hit the boost speed, I believe.

> The puzzle continues with the two shootable blocks in your picture on the left and another booster block below. To solve the entire puzzle, the easiest way is to start your shinespark from the prior room, slide through the blocks shown, then immediately press down after passing through that wall to store the charge; shoot through the shootable blocks and drop into the lower room, climb into the small one-by-one space next to the booster block, then ball-spark to the right to break through a line of blocks. Your reward is a missile tank hidden in the wall.

Comment: Sliding while booting broke the block. However, it was followed by another single tile booster block [slightly above the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x46Ai.jpg).

Comment: @Stevoisiak - yes, it's all one booster puzzle. I can post the full answer under a spoiler tag.

Comment: That would be appreciated

Comment: The answer mentions a ball spark. How do I perform that?

Comment: While in Morph Ball and storing a Shinespark charge, press the jump button (and directional arrow, if desired) to spark in ball form. If no direction is pressed, you should spark upwards.